# Incorrect parameters to 'round' in sql laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

```
$query = $this->restaurant->join('reviews', 'reviews.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id');
        $query = $user_id == null ? $query : $query->where("user_id", $user_id);

        $query = $query->select('restaurants.*')
                        ->selectRaw('ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating) as average_rating)')
                        ->groupBy('restaurants.id')
                        ->havingRaw('AVG(reviews.rating) >= ?', [$request->from_rating])
                        ->havingRaw('AVG(reviews.rating) <= ?', [$request->to_rating])
                        ->orderByDesc("average_rating")
                        ->paginate(
                            $this->perPage, 
                            ['id', 'name', 'image', 'description', 'filesystem', 'created_at'], 
                            'page', 
                            $request->page
                        );

        return $query;
```

My query looks like this. The thing is I want to use ROUND. and when I run this, it tells me

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1583 Incorrect
>   parameters in the call to native function 'round' (SQL: select
>   `restaurants`.*, ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating) as average_rating) from
>   `restaurants` inner join `reviews` on `reviews`.`restaurant_id` =
>   `restaurants`.`id` group by `restaurants`.`id` having
>   AVG(reviews.rating) >= 0 and AVG(reviews.rating) <= 5 order by
>   `average_rating` desc limit 5 offset 0)

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

The `round` part:

```
ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating) as average_rating)
```

should rather look like this:

```
ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating)) as average_rating
```